# Acronyms as description list

Tags: org-mode

I would like to maintain a list of acronyms in my org-mode file. Should I just use [Description plain lists](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html) for that or is there a better way?

Comment: Do these acronyms need any behavior attached to them, or is it just for your own recollection?

Comment: @zck my own recollection, I can't image what kind of behavior I might want to attach to them other than perhaps being able to link to them in an easy way from each place they are referenced (e.g. like the `glossaries` package does in LaTeX).